# Not able to migrate firebase functions to node 10 runtime

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

When i update engine to field to 8 in package.json  it works fine.
But when i move it to 10 it throws error on deploying functions

**package.json**

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  }
```

**firebase deploy**

**Error:**

> package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is
>   unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node":
>   "6"}.

Comment: FYI node 10 is now supported.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version

Answer (score 10):

At the time of this answer, Node 10 is not currently supported by Cloud Functions using the Firebase CLI.  It will be supported in the future.

**EDIT**

As of May 2, 2019, node 10 is a supported runtime when deploying with the Firebase CLI.

Comment: As per my understanding its in Beta so must be aware for use.
Received below communication as  an email
Hello Google Cloud Functions Customer,

We're writing to let you know that the Node.js 6 runtime on Cloud Functions is deprecated and will be decommissioned on April 22, 2020. To avoid any potential disruptions or security risks, please update your functions to use the Node.js 8 (generally available) or Node.js 10 (beta) runtimes as soon as possib

Comment: The Firebase CLI will be updated to support node 10 in the future.

Comment: @DougStevenson How to migrate a function from node 8 to 10? I still get the same error as the OP now when specifying node:10 in package.json and running firebase deploy. Am I missing some step?

Comment: @mikel did you find the answer, I would also like to know

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) is reads:

> Change the `engines` value from `8` to `10` in the `package.json` file that
>   was created in your `functions/` directory during initialization.

(this is locally on your computer)

> ... the entry should look like this: `"engines": {"node": "10"}`

Redeploy using your Firebase CLI (v8.1+) and you should be good to go.